# Laravel - How to map route with logged in user based on organization

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 I am developing multi-organization application without using any package. Also I am using Azure Socialite Login.

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
    protected $username = 'username';

    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::with('azure')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
         $azureUser = Socialite::with('azure')->user();
        try 
        {
            $user = User::where('email', $azureUser->email)->orWhere('username', $azureUser->user['mailNickname'])->first();
            if($user)
            {
                if(Auth::loginUsingId($user->id))
                {
                    $user->update([
                         'last_login_at' => now(),
                    ]);
                   return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
                }
            }
        } 
        catch(\Exception $e) 
        {
            session()->flash("error", "Authentication failed, kindly contact the Administrator!");
            return redirect(route('login'));
        }
    }   
}
```

I have these models:

```
class Organization extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'organizations';
  protected $fillable = [
     'id',
     'org_name',
     'subdomain',   
 ];
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 
        'username',
        'email', 
        'password', 
        'organization_id', 
    ]; 

    public function organization()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Organization');
    }
}
```

I have created a middleware so that I map the route with the organization subdomain.

```
class ConfirmDomain
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $domain == "laraapp";
        $path = $request->getPathInfo(); // should return /laraapp.net or /organization1.laraapp.net
        if (strpos($path, ".") !== false) { // if path has dot.
            list($subdomain, $main) = explode('.', $path);
            if(strcmp($domain, $main) !== 0){
                abort(404); 
            }
        } else{
            if(strcmp($domain, $path) !== 0){
                abort(404); // if domain is not myapp then throw 404 page error
            }
            $subdomain = ""; // considering for main domain value is empty string.
        }

        $org = OrgCompany::where('subdomain', $subdomain)->firstOrFail(); // if not found then will throw 404

        $request->session()->put('subdomain', $org); //store it in session

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Organization table

```
id | org_name           |    subdomain
1  | Main               |
2  | Organization1      |    organization1
```

I want to add main-domain(https://laraapp.net) and sub-domains (https://organization1.laraapp.net) where each will see the data based on the organization_id in each table

```
https://laraapp.net
https://organization1.laraapp.net
```

A user can exit in more that one organization.

When a user logins in with azure socialite, I want the application to check the domain and sub-domain route and use it to get the organization_id, then map it with the organization_id in the user tables.

For instance, if user logs in using https://laraapp.net, the application use it to get the organization_id in the user table, and if it is https://organization1.laraapp.net, it does likewise and so on.

The user should only see the profile based on his organization. Also should only see it's organization data.

How do I achieve this from the route and LoginController?

Comment: read this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing

Comment: Side note: Laravel-5.8 is unsupported. You should upgrade to a supported version. See [Laravel Versions](https://laravelversions.com/) for help.